# "parseerror" while Making an Ajax POST request

Tags: html, node.js, ajax

I'm trying to make a POST request using Ajax in nodeJs. When I run the function `alert(status)` pops up saying `parseerror`. What is wrong with this Ajax call?

```
function ajaxmagic() {
$.ajax({
    url : 'FetchSongs.php',
    type : 'POST',
    data : {username: "maxolgin"},
    dataType: "json",
    success : function (result) {

    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {

    var table = document.getElementById("myMixTable");
    table.style.borderCollapse = "seperate"

    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    console.log(table.rows.length)
    var row = table.insertRow(0);
    var row2 = table.insertRow(1);


    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    cell1.rowSpan = "2"
    cell1.setAttribute("class", "MixImage")


    var image = document.createElement("img");
    image.style.padding = "0px 0px 0px 0px"
    cell1.appendChild(image)

    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    cell2.style.width = "300px"

    var title = document.createElement("td");

    title.innerHTML = result[i].songTitle
    cell2.appendChild(title);

    var artistCell = row2.insertCell(0);

    var artistTitle = document.createElement("td");
    artistTitle.style.fontSize = "13px"
    artistCell.appendChild(artistTitle);

    var timestampCell = row.insertCell(2);
    timestampCell.rowSpan = "2"
    timestampCell.style.horizAlign = "right"


    var timestamp = document.createElement("td");
    timestamp.style.horizAlign = "right"
    timestampCell.appendChild(timestamp);

    }

    },
    error : function (jqxhr, status, exception) {
        alert(status);
    }
    });

}
```

Comment: Check the network tab and your backend logs to see why the request failed

Comment: you're doing this in node.js?

Comment: @law pretty sure. It's a .js file

Answer (score 0):

Whether you are using nodejS, or front end react, you should be using absolute path since i doubt anyone runs nodejs and php on same host and port

`FetchSongs.php` should be changed to `http://hostname:port/FetchSongs.php`